# Why are my Google App Engine Datastore entities reappearing after being deleted?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the Developers Console, in Cloud Datastore > Query, I am trying to delete all entities by clicking the button to select all and then clicking delete. All the entities disappear, but when the page is reloaded they are still there!

Has anyone experienced this at all, and has suggestions?

Comment: Did you try flashing your memcache?

Comment: If you click on one to edit it, do you get an error?  I suspect this is eventual consistency in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted data from your datastore viewer in the app engine console you have to flush the Memcache or wait for a while (minutes)

[image]